# Powershell script for IIS site count

Tags: powershell

I have written a powershell script, which will search for a specific word in IIS:\Sites.if the word is matched then it will automatically bind 443 with SSL certificate. Finally, I need a value which will show how many sites are being matched or updated? So I have written sum of "n" number program for this query. Is there any alternate method in Powershell to find the value other than this?

So here is my code,

```
$site= @((Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites).Name) 
$count=0
echo "All the IIS site have been taken in array"
for($i=0;$i -le $site.count;$i++){
echo "IIS site count"
$hostname=$site[$i] 
echo "ALL sites are now in variable hostname"
if($hostname -match ".8ktest.com"){
echo "searching for the match .8ktest site"
echo "Matching found for .8ktest.com"
echo "Binding in progress"
#New-WebBinding -Name $hostname -IPAddress * -Port 443 -Protocol https -HostHeader $hostname -SslFlags 1
echo "Binding is done "
$cert = (Get-ChildItem "cert:\LocalMachine\my" `
| where-object { $_.Subject -like "*.8ktest.com" } `
| Select-Object -First 1).Thumbprint
$binding = Get-WebBinding -Name $hostname -Protocol https  
if ($binding) {
echo "Adding SSL certificate in progress"
$binding.AddSslCertificate($cert, "my")
echo "succesffully binded 443 in the site $hostname"
$hostname
$count=$hostname.count+$count
}
$count
}
}
else{
echo "No match found "
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of how many sites required a certificate, you can simply just add `$count++` to increment `$count` after your `AddSslCertificate()` method:

```
if ($binding) {
    $binding.AddSslCertificate($cert, "my")
    $count++
}
```

---

If you want to track the count of site names that match the naming criteria, you can consider the following scenarios:

If `$sites` is always a collection (two or more sites), then you can simply do the following:

```
($sites -match '\.8ktest\.com').Count
```

If `$sites` could contain zero or more sites, you will need to handle the scalar and collection scenarios:

```
([regex]::Matches($sites,'\.8ktest\.com') | Where Success).Count
```

---

Since `-match` uses regex, you should technically escape your literal `.` characters. Otherwise `48ktests.com -match '.8ktest.com'` would be `true`.

`-match` works in two modes. When the left-hand side (LHS) is a single item, the operator will return `true` or `false`. If the LHS is a collection, it will return the items that match the condition. So you can't rely on `($item -match 'text').Count` for every situation because, for example, `('nothing' -match 'text').Count` still returns `1` even though the comparison returns `false`.

Using `[regex]::Matches() | Where Success`, you will get consistent results regardless of the item count.

Comment: @Rahul I agree with AdminOfThings. If you want to keep track of how many times you do something, create a counting variable and increment it every time you do that thing. 

@AdminOfThings you can use [comma](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#comma-operator-) to create collections with one object. 

`get-member -inputobject ((,"test") -match "test")`
Result: `TypeName: System.Object[]`

Or zero: `((,"test") -match "no match").count`

Comment: @Mike the unary operator works only for specific situations. It won't work for all cases. `$s = 1,2,3; (,$s) -match 3` yields the whole array, which we don't want.